# Raspberry Pi Pico USB Serial Communication

Tags: python-3.x, serial-port, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

Im trying to code a communication from PC (Linux) Python Programm to my MicroPython Pico but im unable to find a solution for this. Firt of all: I want to use the standard Micro USB Port on my Pico for this. Is this possible?

PC Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import serial

# Serielle Verbindung herstellen
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 115200, timeout=1) #ACM0 is correct. I checked that with dmesg and minicom
command = "reset"
ser.write(command.encode())
ser.close()
```

Raspberry Pico Code:

```
import time

def reset():
    print("Reset called")
    y_pwm.duty_ns(y_default_value_middle)
    time.sleep(0.3)
    x_pwm.duty_ns(x_default_value_middle)


while True:
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        eingabe = input("What do you want to do? (enable_relais, reset): ")
        
        if eingabe == "enable_relais":
            enable_relais()
        elif eingabe == "reset":
            reset()
        else:
            print("Error.")
            
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

If i connect to the serial console via minicom i can see the Pico asking for orders and if im calling `reset` there it moves its servos to the correct positions but if i try to send `reset` with the Python Code above it just does nothing. I need some advice please. How can i just send commands to my pico via my python script?